# Jena Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.9.0:compile (default-compile) on project jena-iri: Fatal error compiling

Tags: java, maven, jena

I try to use Apache Jena with eclipse on my machine.
I'm following the official documentation:

https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/using_jena_with_eclipse.html

Which links to https://jena.apache.org/getting_involved/index.html

with the steps:

1. git clone https://github.com/apache/jena.git
2. cd jena
3. mvn clean install

But I get following error on "mvn clean install"

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.9.0:compile (default-compile) on project jena-iri: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :jena-iri
```

this is what `C:/Users/user/apache-maven-3.8.5/bin/mvn -v` gives me

```
Maven home: C:\Users\user\apache-maven-3.8.5
Java version: 1.8.0_312, vendor: Temurin, runtime: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.312.7-hotspot\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I don't habe admin rights on this computer

Comment: The --release option is only available from JDK9+ not before

Comment: @khmarbaise The official doc says also version 1.8. So should I just install an older maven version? The maven docs says everything with 1.7+ is fine

Comment: Simply wrong. The --release in javac is available since JDK9+ thats it. There is a configuration/property in your pom which assumes different...or you have to use a different JDK version (JDK9+) (BTW: Which official docs?)

Comment: @khmarbaise I dont't have a pom. I just did a checkout from the jena source code (first step in the docs) I have openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_312-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.312-b07, mixed mode) installed

Comment: You don't need to compile jena - the jars are available on maven central.

Comment: If you have checked out the source code theree is a pom file... this page states different about the needed JDK: https://jena.apache.org/download/index.cgi (JDK11!!) and **NOT** JDK8...

Comment: The git repo contains a pom file which requires JDK11+ (https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/main/pom.xml)

Comment: Oh, I guess the doc article is outdated then. Which way would you recommend me for an easy setup of jena? I thought following the official docs will be the easiest

Comment: First I would consume the artifacts from central repository instead of self compiling... (JDK11+) ... further steps ... I think follow the docs...